# How to change values of variable using Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, kotlin-android-extensions

How do I change the value of a variable using the spinner widget.

strings.xml

```
    <string name="selected_item">Selected item:</string>
    <string-array name="Languages">
        <item>English</item>
        <item>Latin</item>
        <item>French</item>
    </string-array>
```

mainactivity

```
        val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
        if (spinner != null) {
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages
            )
            spinner.adapter = adapter

            spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object :
                AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>,
                    view: View, position: Int, id: Long
                ) {
                  
                   //what to do here?
                }

            }
        }
```

suppose I want to change the value of this variable

```
strokeManager.lang = "en"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you will want to use the position to access it from the list that you used to populate the spinner.

```
strokeManager.lang = languageMapToLangCode[languages.get(position)]
```

This should be defined in your class somewhere the spinner can access it

```
val languageMapToLangCode: HashMap<String, String> = hashMapOf("French" to "fr", "Latin" to "ln", "English to "en")
```

Comment: i want to change the string value on selecting item suppose i select latin i want strokeManage.lang = "ln" , for french strokeManage.lang = "fr"

Comment: You will need to create a map that maps the language name to their corresponding language code with the language names as their keys.  I'l update the answer

Comment: do I need to add a .toString() after languageMapToLangCode[languages.get(position)]

Comment: You should not need to because the map is defined  to be of type <String,String> so the language should know that the value from accessing a key value pair from the map is a String already.